# Proving a couple of logical equivalences related to the statement $A \leftrightarrow (B\vee C)$

Tags: first-order-logic

I want to prove a statement of the form $A \leftrightarrow (B\vee C)$. There are a few logical equivalences that seem to be true intuitively, but after learning some math and quantum mechanics, I no longer trust my intuition. Starting with the direction $(B\vee C) \rightarrow A \equiv (B\rightarrow A) \wedge (C \rightarrow A)$, the statement $C \rightarrow A$ is trivial, but to prove $B \rightarrow A$ I need to consider the two cases $B \wedge C$ and $B \wedge \neg C$ separately. It seems that 
\begin{align}
((B\wedge C)\rightarrow A) \wedge ((B\wedge \neg C) \rightarrow A) & \equiv ((B\wedge C)\vee (B\wedge \neg C)) \rightarrow A \\
& \equiv ((B\wedge (C\vee \neg C)) \rightarrow A \\
& \equiv B\rightarrow A
\end{align}

Now, in the other direction $A\rightarrow (B\vee C)$, my intuition tells me that this should be equivalent to proving $((A \wedge \neg C) \rightarrow B) \wedge ((A\wedge C) \rightarrow (B\vee \neg B))$, which are easier statements for me to prove. Drawing on the work done above, we can write
\begin{align}
((A \wedge \neg C) \rightarrow B) \wedge ((A\wedge C) \rightarrow (B\vee \neg B)) & \equiv ((A \wedge \neg C) \rightarrow B) \wedge [((A\wedge C)\rightarrow B) \vee ((A\wedge C) \rightarrow \neg B)] \\
& \equiv [((A\wedge \neg C) \rightarrow B) \wedge ((A\wedge C) \rightarrow B)]\vee [((A\wedge C)\rightarrow \neg B) \wedge ((A\wedge \neg C) \rightarrow B)] \\
&\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \vee [(\neg(A\wedge C)\vee\neg B) \wedge(\neg(A\wedge \neg C) \vee B)] \\
&\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \vee [(\neg A \vee \neg C \vee\neg B) \wedge(\neg A \vee C \vee B)] \\ 
&\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \vee [(\neg A \vee \neg (B \wedge C)) \wedge(\neg A \vee (B\vee C))] \\
&\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \vee[(A\rightarrow \neg(B\wedge C)) \wedge (A\rightarrow (B\vee C))] \\ 
&\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \vee [A\rightarrow ((\neg B\vee \neg C)\wedge (B\vee C))] \\
&\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \vee [A\rightarrow ((\neg B \wedge C) \vee (\neg C \wedge B))] \\
&\equiv A\rightarrow (B\vee (\neg B \wedge C) \vee (\neg C \wedge B)) \\
& \equiv A\rightarrow ((B\vee C)\vee(\neg C \wedge B)) \\ 
& \equiv A\rightarrow (B \vee (C\vee (\neg C \wedge B))) \\
& \equiv A \rightarrow (B \vee (C \vee B)) \\
& \equiv A\rightarrow (B\vee C)
\end{align}

So my intuition appears (to me) to be right in both cases. Unfortunately, I have never learned logic and I deduced these using equivalences I found on Wikipedia so I don't know if I made an error anywhere. Are there any mistakes? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $\boxed{(B\vee C) \rightarrow A}$, it is sufficient to prove that:

- $\boxed{C \rightarrow A}$ (which you say is trivial), and
- $\boxed{(B \land \neg C) \rightarrow A}$ (since if $C$ holds, then you can reuse the work from the previous implication, so for extra information you may assume that $C$ doesn't hold)

To prove $\boxed{A \rightarrow (B\vee C)}$, it is sufficient to prove that:

- $\boxed{(A \land \neg C) \rightarrow B}$ (since if $C$ holds, then we're done, so we may assume that $C$ doesn't hold)